# Get base path in context classes

Tags: php, drupal, behat

How can I get the test's base folder location (in the behat.yml file it's `%behat.path.base%` or `%path.base%`) in the Context classes?
Framework Drupal.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on if you use frameworks and where the Context classes are. A simple `__DIR__ . '/../projectroot/'` can solve this. But some frameworks like Laravel add helpers like `base_path()`.

Comment: Yeah, for me that returns the place where the website files is... The caviar top on this is, I can't use '../' because I need to find and replace in the feature's path to get relative url, which I convert to a filename and then I save a specific place an error log with that filename...